# How to export method call hierarchy from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat

I press `Ctrl+Alt+H` to get method call hierarchy. But when I copy and paste the call hierarchy into in MS Word, I loose the indent level.

How do I export method the call hierarchy from Android Studio and still keep indent level intact?

It should be like this

> method1 [indent level1]
>   --method2 [indent level2]
>   ----method3 [indent level3]
>   ----method4 [indent level3]
>   --method5 [indent level2]
>   ----method6 [indent level3]

But when I copy and paste into Word, I loose the indent level. Every method is in in the same level

```
method1<br>
method2<br>
method3<br>
method4<br>
method5<br>
method6<br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I dont think there is any such way in which you can export method call hierarchy from Android Studio by maintaining its indentation level like the same. I think after exporting method call hierarchy from Android Studio you have to **manually** do the indentation.